# Is $x^TAy = y^TAx$ for any matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that $x^TAy = y^TAx$ is true for symmetric quadratic matrices, but, it is true for non symmetric quadratic matrices?

Comment: Try a simple $2\times 2$ example. It's not hard to find a counter-example

Comment: No it's not true, it might not even make sense to write that if $A$ isn't square to begin with.

Comment: Assuming these are real matrices, we always have $x^T A y = (x^T Ay)^T = y^T A^T x$. Therefore, if $x^TAy = y^T A x$, we have $y^TAx = y^TA^Tx$. Since this must hold for all vectors $x$ and $y$, we can conclude that $A=A^T$, so symmetry is necessary.

Comment: Duplicate : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5063/how-do-i-prove-that-xtay-ytax-if-a-is-symmetric?rq=1

Comment: Any non symmetric matrix will be a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $e_i$ denotes the vector with a $1$ at the $i$-th position and zeros elsewhere. If $A$ is not symmetric, then $a_{ij}\ne a_{ji}$ for some $i\ne j$, but then $e_i^TAe_j=a_{ij}\ne a_{ji}=e_j^TAe_i$.